# jQuery ajax request succeeds on firefox, but not on internet explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to check whether the url shown below is reachable or not.
On firefox the request fails when the page isn't up running, but also no error is shown..
On internet explorer always "success" is displayed. How can i solve this, so that IE is also supported? And why are errors not be displayed anyway? Thanks in advance!

```
var link = "http://localhost:8387/nscalemc/";

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: link,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "script",
    success: function() {
        alert("success")
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax GET request are usually cached by IE. You will need to disbale caching manually:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that doesn't seem to be the solution.. success is displayed anyway, also after cleaning the cache..

Answer (score 0):

**Best solution, instead of doing this in $.ajaxSetup**
Add

```
cache: false
```

to your $.ajax call.

**Another quick fix** 
Change "GET" to "POST" as POST's are not cached.
It depends on your solution if this is a viable workaround.